# Show Image from comming from Api as base64 img src

Tags: angular

I want to show an Image coming from an api as binary file data (as ContentType image/png)

```
  GetRezeptImage(rezeptid: string, type: string): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json').set('Token', this.userService.user.token);
    return this.http.get<any>(environment.portalApiUrl + 'Rezept/RezeptImage/' + rezeptid + '?type=' + type, { headers });
  }
```

```
this.rezeptService.GetRezeptImage(this.rezeptId, this.type).subscribe(binData => {
      var base64img = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(binData);
      this.image = base64img;
      console.log('bin', binData);
      console.log('b64', base64img);
    });
```

I get an HttpErrorResponse Exception in the Browser console with the following Message:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHtt…, text: "�PNG
↵↵
IHDR�3����sRGB���…*ڽ�v�m���3*�vo#汰  ��Y'+�ӿ����^�e

Does anyone know what i do wrong?!

Comment: You need to tell the service you want to get a blob response. Check this link: https://brianflove.com/2017/11/02/angular-http-client-blob/

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the HTTP header to accept application/json data. But the data you receive is binary. Angulars HTTP module will try to convert your binary data to JSON but fails, because it is not valid JSON.

Try to remove or set another content type header

Answer (score 0):

You're not expecting a JSON, but you want a BLOB. You set it like this...

```
this.httpClient.get('randomurl.com', { responseType: 'blob'}).subscribe(...)
```